# How to import Geonames into SQLite?

Tags: sqlite, import, terminal, geonames

I need to import the Geonames database (http://download.geonames.org/export/dump/) into SQLite (file is about a gigabyte in size, ±8,000,000 records, tab-delimited).

I'm using the built-in SQLite-possibilities of Mac OS X, accessed through terminal. All goes well, until record 381174 (tested with older file, the exact number varies slightly depending on the exact version of the Geonames database, as it is updated every few days), where the error "expected 19 columns of data but found 18" is displayed.

The exact line causing the problem is:

> 126704    Gora Kyumyurkey Gora Kyumyurkey Gora Kemyurkey,Gora
>   Kyamyar-Kup,Gora Kyumyurkey,Gora Këmyurkëy,Komur Qu",Komur
>   Qu',Komurkoy Dagi,Komūr Qū’,Komūr Qū”,Kummer Kid,Kömürköy Dağı,kumwr
>   qwʾ,كُمور
>   قوء   38.73335    48.24133    T   MT  AZ  AZ  00              0       2471    Asia/Baku   2014-03-05

I've tested various countries separately, and the western countries all completely imported without a problem, causing me to believe the problem is somewhere in the exotic characters used in some entries. (I've put this line into a separate file and tested with several other database-programs, some did give an error, some imported without a problem).

How do I solve this error, or are there other ways to import the file?

Thanks for your help and let me know if you need more information.

Comment: How exactly are you importing? What separator character are you using, and how many are in that line?

Comment: The file is tab-delimited, so all values are separated by tabs. There are a total of 19 values for every entry, for more information see the link I provided where it is explained exactly how the file is formatted (or download a smaller file for testing).

Comment: Which SQLite version?

Answer (score 1):

Regarding the question title, a preliminary search resulted in

the GeoNames format description ("tab-delimited text in utf8 encoding")

- https://download.geonames.org/export/dump/readme.txt

some libraries (untested):

- Perl: https://github.com/mjradwin/geonames-sqlite (+ autocomplete demo JavaScript/PHP)
- PHP: https://github.com/robotamer/geonames-to-sqlite
- Python: https://github.com/commodo/geonames-dump-to-sqlite

GUI (mentioned by @charlest):

- https://github.com/sqlitebrowser/sqlitebrowser/

The SQLite tools have import capability as well:

- https://sqlite.org/cli.html#csv_import

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a bi-directional text issue. "كُمور قوء" is expected to be at the end of the comma-separated alternate name list. However, on account of it being dextrosinistral (or RTL), it's displaying on the wrong side of the latitude and longitude values.

I don't have visibility of your import method, but it seems likely to me that that's why it thinks a column is missing.

Answer (score 0):

I found the same problem using the script from the geonames forum here: http://forum.geonames.org/gforum/posts/list/32139.page

Despite adjusting the script to run on Mac OS X (Sierra 10.12.6) I was getting the same errors. But thanks to the script author since it helped me get the sqlite database file created.

After a little while I decided to use the sqlite DB Browser for SQLite (version 3.11.2) rather than continue with the script.

I had errors with this method as well and found that I had to set the "Quote character" setting in the import dialog to the blank state. Once that was done the import from the FULL allCountries.txt file ran to completion taking just under an hour on my MacBookPro (an old one but with SSD).

Although I have not dived in deeper I am assuming that the geonames text files must not be quote parsed in any way. Each line simply needs to be handled as tab delimited UTF-8 strings.

At the time of writing allCountries.txt is 1.5GB with 11,930,517 records. SQLite database file is just short of 3GB.

Hope that helps.

UPDATE 1:
Further investigation has revealed that it is indeed due to the embedded quotes in the geonames files, and looking here: https://sqlite.org/quirks.html#dblquote shows that SQLite has problems with quotes. Hence you need to be able to switch off quote parsing in SQLite.

Despite the 3.11.2 version of DB Browser being based on SQLite 3.27.2 which does not have the required mods to ignore the quotes, I can only assume it must be escaping the quotes when you set the "Quote character" to blank.